# Given a list of 10 random numbers in the range from 0-99 (100 Numbers), what is the probability the list contains all evens? all odds?

Tags: probability

So I'm trying to solve this problem that I came up with, basically I want to generate a randomized list of integers. The integers can be any value from 0 to 99, thus we have 100 elements in the sample space.

So what I know is we have 100 elements, and we want to choose 10 items from the list randomly. The probability of each number picked is even is $\frac{1}{2}$.

I'm not sure how to continue from here.

EDIT: There can be replacement, so duplicates can be allowed.

Could we possibly use Bernoulli Trials?

Comment: You should specify whether or not you are choosing "with replacement" or not,  Would you consider ten $1's$ to be a valid selection?  If you do, then you are right about the $\frac 12$ probability in each case...but is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes, with replacement. Just edited.

Comment: Then bernoulli is not relevant...the answer is just $\left( \frac 1{2}\right)^{10}$.  Note that if you exclude duplicates, the probability goes down considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google says
 -

> (50 choose 10)/(100 choose 10) =  0.0006

That's the probability that you get all evens when you pick 10 numbers from the first 100. The probability is the same for all odds.

That's for choosing without replacement.

If you replace each time then each choice is just a coin flip and the probability of $10$ heads is $1/2^{10} = 1/1024 \approx 0.001$.

Comment: Could you explain again why it's 50 Choose 10? Is it because we know there are 50 even numbers, and we want to pick 10 numbers from those 50 evens, and then we just divide over the denominator which is the total number of possibilities? And also why is it just a "coin flip" with replacement?

Comment: @Stuy  Your explanation is correct. No need for me to explain again.

Answer (score 0):

If the selection with replacement, then is similar to the problem with a box with 50 red balls (even numbers) and 50 white balls (odd numbers). Don't care the number (1 is the same than 3, or five, seven,...)

The probability of choose a red ball is $p = \dfrac{50\,red\,balls}{100\,balls} = \dfrac{1}{2}$

With replacement, if we name the 10 events of selection $S_1,...,S_{10}$, then selection $S_i$ is independent from selection $S_j$ where $i\neq j$ $\rightarrow P(S_1=red, S_2=red, ..., S_{10}=red) = P(S_1=red).P(S_2=red)...P(S_{10}=red)={(\dfrac{1}{2})}^{10}$